# boost::is_nothrow_move_constructible implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm giving the new VS 2015 Preview a go, and I'm having some trouble with Boost. But after tracing the problem, I don't understand how it *ever* worked on *any* compiler.

I have an `unordered_map<K, boost::variant<std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<T>>>>`. This fails to compile because the `boost::variant` apparently tries to copy-construct the `unordered_map` inside it- based on the result of the `boost::is_nothrow_move_constructible` trait, which is indeed `boost::false_type`.

This reveals the definition of `boost::is_nothrow_move_constructible` as

```
template <class T>
struct is_nothrow_move_constructible_imp{
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value =(
        ::boost::type_traits::ice_and<
            ::boost::type_traits::ice_or<
                ::boost::has_trivial_move_constructor<T>::value,
                ::boost::has_nothrow_copy<T>::value
            >::value,
            ::boost::type_traits::ice_not< ::boost::is_array<T>::value >::value
        >::value));
};
```

Er, what about non-trivial noexcept move constructors, like many, many classes have? How can this definition function on other compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the real confusion here is that it never did work on Visual Studio. I guess that must have been only `optional` and not `variant` where I previously used move-only types. It seems that `variant` effectively cannot support move-only types on Visual Studio for any current version, and my memories of it working on VS2013 are clearly incorrect.

I ended up simply specializing the trait for the types I'm using. Hacky but functional.